# Django ORM not generating correct SQL for many to many not in

Tags: python, django, orm, many-to-many

I'm having a problem with Django's generated SQL from the ORM.

`Cartons` have a many to many relationship with `Shipments` through `cartons_shipments`.

I'm looking to exclude Shipments where they have at least one `INBOUND` Carton that has a status in `['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE']`.

But I was not getting the results I expected so I turned on the SQL logging.

```py
return Shipment.objects.filter(
    ... # other filtering
    # does not have any inbound cartons in_transit/delivered/failed
    ~Q(
        Q(cartons__type='INBOUND') &
        Q(cartons__status__in=['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE'])
    ) &
).distinct()
```

I have also tried this as my filter but got the same SQL output.

```
~Q(
    cartons__type='INBOUND', 
    cartons__status__in=['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE']
)
```

This generates this SQL:

```sql
AND NOT (
    "shipments"."id" IN (
        SELECT U1."shipment_id" 
        FROM "cartons_shipments" U1 
        INNER JOIN "cartons" U2 ON (U1."carton_id" = U2."id") 
        WHERE U2."type" = 'INBOUND'
    ) 
    AND "shipments"."id" IN (
        SELECT U1."shipment_id" FROM "cartons_shipments" U1 
        INNER JOIN "cartons" U2 ON (U1."carton_id" = U2."id") 
        WHERE U2."status" IN ('TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE')
    )
)
```

But this isn't correct as it would exclude shipments where it has **any**  `INBOUND` cartons and shipments where **any** carton (not necessarily `INBOUND` cartons) has a status is in `['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE']`. I need this logic combined.

Also now I'm running 2 sub selects and taking a significant performance hit because we have a ton of cartons in those statuses.

The correct SQL would be something like:

```sql
AND NOT ("shipments"."id" IN (
    SELECT U1."shipment_id" 
    FROM "cartons_shipments" U1 
    INNER JOIN "cartons" U2 ON (U1."carton_id" = U2."id") 
    WHERE U2."type" = 'INBOUND'
    and U2."status" IN ('TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE')
))
```

This way I would only be excluding shipments with `INBOUND` Cartons in those statuses.

The query time between these two is significant and of course I'm able to get the correct results with the 2nd SQL example. I thought that I could combine that logic by combining the `Q()` objects. But can't figure it out.

I have also thought that maybe I could just right the raw SQL in the 2nd example. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to combine raw sql with other ORM filters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit:

I'm able to get the correct result by doing the filtering in code and removing the filter from the query:

```
returned_cartons = Carton.objects.prefetch_related('shipments').filter(
    type='INBOUND',
    status__in=['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE']
)

returned_shipment_ids = list(map(
    lambda carton: carton.shipments.first().id,
    returned_cartons
))

return list(filter(
    lambda shipment: shipment.id not in returned_shipment_ids,
    shipments
))
```

This unfortunately is too slow to be useful.

---

Final solution based on Endre Both's idea

```
return Shipment.objects.filter(
    ...,  # other filtering
    # has at least 1 inbound carton
    Q(cartons__type='INBOUND')
).exclude(
    # we want to exclude shipments that have at least 1 inbound cartons
    # with a status in transit/delivered/failure
    id__in=Shipment.objects.filter(
        ...,  # filters to limit the number of records returned
        cartons__type='INBOUND',
        cartons__status__in=['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE'],
    ).distinct()
).distinct()
```

This line `Q(cartons__type='INBOUND')` is required because we are excluding Shipments that have an `INBOUND` Carton in `['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE']` statuses. But we would also keep Shipments that don't have any Cartons.

Hope this helps more people out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To us mere mortals, the "M" in ORM can be a bit inscrutable at times. But you could try a different, simpler tack. It still uses a subquery and not a join, but this is not necessarily a performance drag.

```
Shipment.objects.exclude(
    id__in=Cartons.objects
        .filter(type='INBOUND',
                status__in=['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE'])
        .values('shipments__id')
        .distinct()
)
```

The exact name of the reference back to the `Shipment` primary key from the `Carton` model depends on the exact definition of the models. I've used `shipments__id`, but it could be `shipment_set__id` or something else.

---

New idea: You need to base the subselect on the intermediate model rather than `Cartons`. If you have an explicit intermediate model, it's easy, if you don't, you first need a `Shipment` or `Cartons` object, because as far as I know you cannot get a reference to the intermediate model from the class itself, only from an instance.

```
IModel = Shipment.objects.first().cartons.through
Shipment.objects.exclude(
    id__in=IModel.objects
        .filter(cartons__type='INBOUND',
                cartons__status__in=['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE'])
        .values('shipment__id')
        .distinct()
)
```

Comment: I love this idea. Unfortunately still getting some bad SQL. ```AND NOT ("shipments"."id" IN (
SELECT DISTINCT U1."shipment_id" FROM "cartons" U0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "cartons_shipments" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."carton_id") 
WHERE (U0."status" IN ('TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE') AND U0."type" = 'INBOUND'))));``` The Left Outer Join is messing it up.

Comment: Is it really, ie. did you verify that you get bogus data? I'm not an SQL whiz, but how is a left outer join different from an inner join when you are only selecting from the right hand side of the join (the shipment id from the intermediate table)?

Comment: It may add `null` to the excluded shipment ids, but while keeping count of the nulls may be a minor inefficiency, it shouldn't affect results.

Comment: It does appear to be changing the result. With an inner join the results appear to be correct! So great idea with this. But with the left join I'm not getting any rows back in the result. I with you though. I'm not sure why the `null` rows would mess anything up.

Comment: By adding `shipments__is_null=False` to our filter in the excludes, I ended up getting:
`AND NOT ("shipments"."id" IN (
SELECT DISTINCT U1."shipment_id" FROM "cartons" U0 
INNER JOIN "cartons_shipments" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."carton_id") 
WHERE (
 U1."shipment_id" IS NOT NULL 
 AND U0."status" IN ('TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE') 
 AND U0."type" = 'INBOUND'
)))`. Little repetitive with the inner join and null check but this looks like it is giving me back the correct rows!

Comment: I cannot fathom why `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` can make a difference here (with everything else equal), but I've had a flash of insight this morning anyway, see update.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Endre. I ended up kinda combining what you suggested.
`Shipment.objects.filter(
    ...,  # other filters to limit the number of rows returned
    cartons__type='INBOUND',
    cartons__status__in=['TRANSIT', 'DELIVERED', 'FAILURE'],
).distinct()`

Comment: Man I wish the code formatting was better in the comments... :)

Comment: You can always append updated code to the question body.