# Django odd behaviour with Q objects and `and_` (vs `and`)

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to dynamically construct list of filters based on some function arguments.
I build a list of predicates using `Q` objects and finally I construct one predicate with:

```
filters = []
... some code appending Q objects to filters ...
combined_filter = reduce(and_, filters)
```

Then I query my database objects with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(combined_filter)
```

I have noticed a bit odd behaviour when I try to combine `Q` objects with `operator.and_`.

For example comparing output of:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(and_(is_metal, ~is_wood))
print([i.name for i in items])

items = Item.objects.filter(is_metal and ~is_wood)
print([i.name for i in items])

items = Item.objects.filter(is_metal, ~is_wood)
print([i.name for i in items])
```

I get:

```
['Table', 'Container']
['Container']
['Table', 'Container']
```

What is the reason for different behaviour between `and_` and `and`?

My expected output is to get just `['Container']` (see below for full example, "Container" is the only thing with only "metal" as material, "Table" should be excluded because it also has "wood").

Followup question would be: how do I get behaviour of `and` when using `reduce`?

My django version is 2.0.7
I have reproduced that exact problem on https://repl.it/repls/AgonizingBossyEfficiency

In case above link dies all code I've modified is below:

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Material(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  materials = models.ManyToManyField(Material)
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models import Q
from operator import and_
from .models import Material, Item

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    with transaction.atomic():
      metal = Material(name="metal")
      metal.save()
      wood = Material(name="wood")
      wood.save()

      table = Item(name="Table")
      table.save()
      table.materials.add(metal, wood)
      table.save()

      chair = Item(name="Chair")
      chair.save()
      chair.materials.add(wood)
      chair.save()

      container = Item(name="Container")
      container.save()
      container.materials.add(metal)
      container.save()

      is_metal = Q(materials__name__in = ('metal',))
      is_wood = Q(materials__name__in = ('wood',))

      items = Item.objects.filter(and_(is_metal, ~is_wood))
      print([i.name for i in items])

      items = Item.objects.filter(is_metal and ~is_wood)
      print([i.name for i in items])

      items = Item.objects.filter(is_metal, ~is_wood)
      print([i.name for i in items])

      raise Exception('nope')
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579372/python-django-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operator-and-the-o.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Ilja my question is effectively a duplicate.

My main problem was thinking that `operator.and_` applies logical `and`.
However that is not the case, `operator.and_` is a bitwise operator.

If I compare behaviour of `operator.and_(is_metal, is_wood)` to `is_metal & is_wood` (as opposed to `is_metal && is_wood` == `is_metal and is_wood`) I do get the same results.

So my problem was that I was using bitwise and where I wanted logical and.

Comment: Careful there. The [documented way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#s-complex-lookups-with-q-objects) of combining Q objects is with bitwise and, i.e. `&` or `_and` which are identical as you correctly concluded. However, as described in the question marked as a duplicate, when using `and`, you end up with the last Q object only, i.e. `filter(is_metal and ~is_wood)` is equivalent to `filter(~is_wood)` or even `filter('hi there' and ~is_wood)`. This is hardly what you want.

Comment: The reason you got the expected results with the wrong `and` and unexpected results with the correct `_and` lies in the intricacies of correctly defining a multi-criteria filter for the many side of an x-to-many relationship - this is what you should be [looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54841016/filtering-on-many-to-many-relations-that-fulfill-a-set-of-criteria/54844688#54844688) [into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540927/django-orm-not-generating-correct-sql-for-many-to-many-not-in/55542110#55542110).

Comment: Thanks @EndreBoth. Both comments are useful.
I've worked out first myself after a bit of pondering and then I realised my issue with many-to-many query.
I still find `filter` and `Q.__and__` quite confusing.